# What is stochastic independence and how it is different from physical independence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a experiment that you ask the first person you meet on the street in which month her birthday falls.

The sample space is

$S= \{ Janua\color{red}ry , Feb\color{red}rua\color{red}ry ,Ma\color{red}rch  ,Ap\color{red}ril ,May, June ,July, August ,Septembe\color{red}r ,Octobe\color{red}r, Novembe\color{red}r, Decembe\color{red}r \}$

Now consider the events:

L : "born in a long month i.e months with 31 days"

R: "born in a month with the letter  r"

H : "born in the first half of the year"

Clearly,

$P(H)= 1/2$

$P(H/R)= 1/2$

*So $H$ and $R$ are independent*

Also

$P(H \cap L ) =1/4$      and       $P(L)=7/12$

but , $1/2×7/12 \neq 1/4$

So we conclude  $L$ and $H$ are dependent.

Why it is that $R$ & $H$ are independent but $L$ & $H$ are dependent?

Till now i have considered that physical dependence and independence ( means what we refer even non mathematically) was same as stochastic dependence and independence.

But after this above e.g, i am not able to actually understand what does stochastic independence means?

So to be really be sure that events are stochastically independence we have to rely on mathematical formulas (not that i am complaining) ?

Comment: Maybe you can highlight the letter r at the months like  $Janua\color{red}ry$

Comment: Roughly speaking, the notions coincide.   In plain English, "Independent" means that knowing about $A$ does not alter your estimate regarding $B$.  Mathematically, $P(B\,|\,A)=P(B)$.  It gets a little unintuitive with continuous probabilities (where you can have possible events with probability $0$).

Comment: @lulu then what about this e.g why it is so?

Comment: You mean your months questions?  But those cases just follow from the definitions, as you have remarked.  You can't reasonably expect that independence will always be obvious.  That's what the math is for...it gives you a way to confirm (or negate) independence even when intuition fails.